# DreamBox (enigma2-based) to play multicast streams

Tags: media-player, embedded-linux

I have a couple of [DM800HDs](http://www.dream-multimedia-tv.de/en/dm-800-hd-pvr) running [Open Dreambox](http://opendreambox.org/) and I want to stream all the media to them through a UDP multicast from VLC ([something like this](http://vvcap.net/db/202XorCh2bOalIqf9IED.htp)). Those boxes would be un-manned, so I want them to boot into RTP mode and stay that way, just play what is being broadcast by VLC server. Open Dreambox runs an enigma2 player.

I am not sure where to start with this. First off, I need to be able to put them into a mode where they would listen to a milticast stream. I tried vlcf, but it does not seem to offer such functionality. Then I need to turn them in such mode on a boot time instead of via GUI.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the environment to test it, but from what i've learned online I would recommend trying a M3U file on the harddisk/flash of the dreambox. If you choose that via menu or web remote control, the dreambox will join the multicast.

I guess it is easy to get the dreambox to start on that file, if no other is available.

(tags: enigma enigma2 m3u multicast igmp dreambox [iptv]

Comment: I gave up on dreambox, so I'm not sure if your solution works or not, I assume it does. Since you were the only one who answered, I'm considering your answer it.